# Git checkout when tests are tracked

Tags: git, testing

I am in the process of (hopefully) squashing a bug in a Ruby gem.

I branched out, and wrote some tests on top of my repository, but now I can't checkout to another commit in order to run my tests on it.

How do you checkout or bisect while keeping and running your tests?

Comment: You could clone into another directory while they run, then merge when they're complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert, but if there are no hard-coded references to test directories, just copying the tests directory (thus making an untracked subdirectory in your project) should work. You can simply delete it when you no longer need the "frozen" tests.